# .htaccess URL rewriting for clean user profile urls

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite the URL of the users profile page to be more clean.

```
https://example.com/user/profile.php?user=username
```

to

```
https://example.com/username
```

I have looked around for a solution and read some documentation but I can't quite figure out how to get it right.

I have this code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I run this code I get an internal server error each time but I ran my code through htaccesscheck.com and it said my syntax was all good. So I'm guessing that my problem stems from my lack of knowledge on htaccess.

I should also mention I have another RewriteRule to remove the .php extension from the URL. Not sure if this would affect anything, but if it would than I can follow up with my whole .htaccess file.

**EDIT:**

I did check error logs and I guess I should have put that here in the beginning, my bad. It outputted this:

```
RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

Full .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
Options +MultiViews
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
IndexIgnore *


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/profile?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: "I have another RewriteRule to remove the .php extension" - You may a have a conflict. And this could result in a rewrite loop (which will manifest itself as a 500 error in the browser). Please include the full contents of your `.htaccess` file. Incidentally, if you get a 500 error, you should check the servers error log for the details of this error.

Comment: @MrWhite I updated my question with the output log error, and the rest of my .htaccess. Thanks.

Comment: Search [RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=RewriteRule%3A+bad+flag+delimiters&t=canonical&ia=web) for similar cases. Not reproducible from a text copy and paste here. // And anyway, those two rules are barely compatible with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter name in first example is `user` and then you set as `username`.

```
Options +Indexes
Options +MultiViews
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/profile?user=$1 [QSA,L] # <<< see this line
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] # <<< this should be the last line in rules
```

Moreover, is the `mod_rewrite` module enabled in your web server?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/profile?username=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This is very different to the code you initially posted. There are also no "bad flag delimiters" here, unless there is a character in your source code that has not been copied? If, for example, you had `[QSA, L]` (with a space) then that would have triggered such an error.

You've also changed the URL parameter name from `user` to `username`?

However, this code will certainly trigger a rewrite loop, as the last `RewriteRule` executes unconditionally and applies to *everything*. The `RewriteCond` directive (that checks that the request maps to a file) only applies to the single `RewriteRule` that follows.

These directives also conflict, since the first rule will try to append `.php` when requesting `/username`. This could be avoided by checking that the file with a `.php` extension exists before rewriting to it. (Unless there is a more restrictive pattern you can use for the URL-path - which would be preferable - since file system checks are relatively expensive.)

You also need to disable `MultiViews` - you have *enabled* it on the second line. MultiViews and your directive to append the file extension will conflict.

Try something like the following instead:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ user/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Unless you have a specific requirement to display an empty directory listing when viewing a directory then just disable directory indexes altogether (as above). The user then gets a 403 and no chance of it getting indexed by search engines.

There is no need to backslash escape the literal dot inside a regex character class.

`^([^/.]+)$` is a more restrictive pattern to avoid a rewrite loop. Your previous pattern matched *everything* and since there was no filesystem check, it would have rewritten the rewrite etc. etc.

You should rewrite to the actual file, ie. `profile.php` (as you did in your first example), rather rely on another directive to append the `.php`.